# How to to run all the scenarios of one feature file in single browser instance

Tags: serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

How to to run all the scenarios of one feature file in single browser instance. @After and@Before hooks instantiate after each scenario, Can't we execute them before all scenarios once and after all scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

I assume when you say "single browser instance", you are talking about not restarting the browser between tests.

You need to add

```
serenity.restart.browser.for.each = feature
```

in your [serenity.properties](https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-documentation/blob/master/src/asciidoc/system-props.adoc).